# Remove item from registry's container | C# .NET | IoC | StructureMap

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, structuremap

Consider the following code segment:

```
var registry = new Registry();
registry.For<TInterfaceA>().Use<TImplementationA>();
registry.For<TInterfaceB>().Use<TImplementationB>();
registry.For<TInterfaceC>().Use<TImplementationC>();

var container = new Container(registry);
```

Is there a way in which I may remove the `registry` that contains `TInterfaceB` which resolves to `TImplementationB`.

For instance:

```
container.RemoveRegistry(TInterfaceB );
```

Comment: They have a ClearAll to override any registration. Why would you need to remove it? Ie, not replace it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Just use ClearAll method on configuration expression.

Example:

```
var registry = new Registry();
registry.For<TInterfaceA>().Use<TImplementationA>();

var container = new Container(registry);
//this would be working
var test1 = container.GetInstance<TInterfaceA>();

container.Configure(conf => conf.For<TInterfaceA>().ClearAll());
//this throw StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException
//var test2 = container.GetInstance<TInterfaceA>();
```

[Full description from documentation](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/clear-or-replace/)